# Notation for pluralizing a number

Tags: notation

Which is the more accepted notation in mathematics for pluralizing a number: $0$'s or $0$s? i.e. should the pluralized number contain an apostrophe.

P.S. Not sure if this is as an acceptable question for this forum.

Comment: why not say "zeroes" to avoid the issue. And yes there may be a better site for such grammar type questions, but I don't know what it is...

Comment: Usually, you write the whole word for numbers smaller than 10.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not